# Partitioning a List of Tuples by Value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, partitioning

i have a list of tuples in Python and want to split it into N Parts based on the Value of the Tuple so i end up with N Parts where the sum of the Value in the contained tuples is as equal as possible.

So if this is my raw data:

`data=[('test',2),('bob',2),('carol',3),('ted',4),('alice',3)]`

split into 2 parts would be this:

`part1 = [('test',2),('bob',2),('carol',3)]`
`part2 = [('ted',4),('alice',3)]`

Is there any way to easly do this in Python 3?

Comment: Do you mean if there is a function for this?

Comment: Do you care about performance?

Comment: no performance is not really an issue. just the finish counts in this case

Answer (score 0):

We could write a recursive function to compute the most optimal split (or partition).

*Mind you, the complexity is O(2^N) and its expected that way for any partition-creation problems.*

Here is the working code:

```
from copy import copy


def partition(S, A, B):
    if len(S) == 0:
        return abs(sum([x[1] for x in A]) - sum(x[1] for x in B)), A, B

    el = S.pop()
    aval, A1, B1 = partition(S.copy(), A.copy() + [el], B.copy())
    bval, A2, B2 = partition(S.copy(), A.copy(), B.copy() + [el])

    if aval < bval:
        return aval, A1, B1
    else:
        return bval, A2, B2


data=[('test',2),('bob',2),('carol',3),('ted',4),('alice',3)]
mindiff, A, B = partition(data, [], [])

print(A, B, "|| Partition-diff:", mindiff)
```

Output:

```
**[('carol', 3), ('bob', 2), ('test', 2)] [('alice', 3), ('ted', 4)]** || Partition-diff: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a generic function like this

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def partition(items: Iterable[T], predicate: Callable[[T], bool]) -> Tuple[List[T], List[T]]:
    "Splits items into list of true values and list of false values"
    return list(filter(predicate, items)), list(filterfalse(predicate, items))

print(partition([1, 2, 3, 4], lambda i: i >2))
>>> ([3, 4], [1, 2])
```

There's no built-in function for this as far as I know.

The idea behind providing the `predicate` parameter is that you can provide your own function that takes an item, and returns a boolean to determine which result set it would be in.